# Plugin Height Displayed Differently Between Online & Mobile

Tags: plugins, banno-digital-toolkit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Uvt.png)I set this up as a dashboard card plugin, but I set the initial height to "0" and it displays properly in an online browser (see attached), but in the mobile app, it still shows part of the website (see attached).  Why would the mobile display differently?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two pictures...

Comment: I will update the image.  There is a difference in the card for "Apply for a Mortgage" for both Mobile and Desktop.  Hope the new image helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for adding the image comparison. It looks like we have a difference in handling a zero height between Banno Online and Banno Mobile (in this case, I believe that is an image from the iOS app). We've noted this discrepancy based upon your report, thank you.

FYI: we don't intend for plugins to have a zero height for the Card Face. We'll address this issue by restricting the height to be greater than zero when configuring a plugin.

Comment: Thanks Jaime.  The reason I chose a zero height is because I didn't want the website to display inside the card.  All I wanted was the apply now option to display in the card.  Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: The Digital Toolkit doesn't support that particular use case. The discrepancy between the various platforms in handling a zero-height plugin is not intended behavior.